# what to use instead of eval in jquery

Tags: jquery, eval

I am trying to use fancybox jquery plugin in my view. I am sending a js string to fancybox method. but it is not working. I think it ask it should be an object. I dont know really how to do that. Let me show you my code. My problem stil continue! what might cause that problem?

This way it is not working.

```
$('.adsImgDiv').click(function(){
        var myFancy = $(this).attr('imgVal');

        $.fancybox.open([
                myFancy
                ]);
    });
```

But this way it works

```
$('.adsImgDiv').click(function(){
        var myFancy = $(this).attr('imgVal');

        $.fancybox.open([
                { href:'http://127.1.0.1:14031/resources/advimages/0_03e23e4f-4c63-419a-94ef-911de63fb368.png', title:'titlein'} ,{ href:'http://127.1.0.1:14031/resources/advimages/1_03e23e4f-4c63-419a-94ef-911de63fb368.png', title:'super'}
                ]);
    });
```

Last error

Error getting for parseJson

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token h jquery-1.8.3.min.js:541
jQuery.extend.parseJSON jquery-1.8.3.min.js:541
(anonymous function)   myAds:218jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.8.3.min.js:3074elemData.handle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function .parseJSON for that.

```
$('.adsImgDiv').click(function(){
    var myFancy = $(this).attr('imgVal');

    $.fancybox.open([
        $.parseJSON(myFancy)
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Thnaks for your answer. I updated my question. When I try $.parseJSON it show that error. Iam using jquery 1.8.3

Comment: Do a little debugging like outputting on the console the variable myFancy

Comment: $.parseJSON is not working. I removed $.fancybox.open and just added var json = $.parseJSON(myFancy); alert(json);  but it has same error. I think I have a problem with $.parseJSON. my jquery library doesnt recognize it

Comment: Copy the output and harcode the $.fancybox.open(["paste here"]); to see what happens.

Comment: with "" quotes fancy works but it pop up the string just. when remove "" quotes it shows images as desire.

Comment: your answer were correct. my json formar was wrong.